# Extract child nodes without losing connection to the parent using xml2

Tags: r, xml, xml2

Suppose I have the following XML:

```
library(xml2)

x = xml_children(read_xml('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <items>
    <item type="greeting" id="9273938">
      <link type="1" id="139" value="Hi"/>
      <link type="1" id="142" value="Hello"/>
      <link type="1" id="130" value="Ahoy"/>
    </item>
    <item type="greeting" id="9225694">
      <link type="1" id="138" value="Bye"/>
      <link type="1" id="131" value="Adios"/>
    </item>
  </items>'))
```

I can loop over it to access the `<link>` nodes in the individual `<item>` nodes.

```
lapply(x, xml_find_all, xpath = "link")
```

This produces a list of separate nodesets, which allows me to know which collection of "links" belongs to which "item". But looping over a longish nodeset (say thousands of `<item>` nodes) can be slow.

In contrast the below is almost instant (and I think closer to the spirit of how xml2 should be used) but I no longer know which item the links came from. They appear to all be siblings:

```
xml_find_all(x, xpath = "link")
```

Question: How to extract the `<link>` nodes without losing information about the `<item>` they came from, avoiding the lapply solution above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With each `link` node, you can get the information about the parent item by `/parent::item`:

```
library(xml2)

x <- read_xml('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <items>
    <item type="greeting" id="9273938">
      <link type="1" id="139" value="Hi"/>
      <link type="1" id="142" value="Hello"/>
      <link type="1" id="130" value="Ahoy"/>
    </item>
    <item type="greeting" id="9225694">
      <link type="1" id="138" value="Bye"/>
      <link type="1" id="131" value="Adios"/>
    </item>
  </items>')
links <- x %>% xml_find_all("//link")
data.frame(
  item_id = links %>% xml_find_first("./parent::item") %>% xml_attr("id"), # notice the dot refers to the current link node
  link_id = links %>% xml_attr("id"),
  value = links %>% xml_attr("value")
)
```

Comment: Well done! One doubt though: Both `xml_find_all(x, "//link")` and `xml_find_all(x, "link")` seem to produce the same result. But on my data (~600 item nodes, each item has multiple other nodes besides links) using `link` without the slashes is _massively_ faster (~60ms vs full 29s with slashes). Any idea why that is?

Comment: @jakub Tbh, I didn't know that using `link` without slashes would work. As I've learned XPath, to get all nodes with names, use `//link`.

Comment: If you are interested: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63853413/2416535

Comment: @jakub Thanks. That's helpful.

Comment: @jakub But it's still kinda confusing because children of the document are items tho.