# Why is "link" faster than "//link" in XPath?

Tags: r, xml, xpath, xml2

Given this XML,

```
library(xml2)

text = paste0(
  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><items>',
  paste(rep(
  '<item type="greeting" id="9273938">
     <link type="1" id="139" value="Hi"/>
     <link type="1" id="142" value="Hello"/>
   </item>', 100),
        collapse = "\n"),
  '</items>')

x = xml_children(read_xml(text))
```

I can select all the link nodes by using `"link"` or `"//link"` and get the same result – but with very different speed:

```
bench::mark(
     link  = xml_find_all(x,   "link"),
  `//link` = xml_find_all(x, "//link"))[1:5]

# A tibble: 2 x 5
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>
1 link          1.5ms   1.56ms     606.     10.6KB
2 //link       27.1ms  55.74ms      15.2   558.2KB
```

Why is there such a big difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `"link"` only has to check if the current node has a child element named `link`, whereas `"//link"` has to check all elements in the document to see which are named `link`.

**XPath notes:**

- `"link"` only checks the immediate children of the current node because
  the default axis is the `child::` axis.
- `"//link"` checks all elements in the document because `//` is a shortcut for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`, so `"//link"` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/child::link`.

Comment: @kjhughes It's still confusing to me. The children of the current node (the document) are the `<items>` tag though, not the `<link>` tags. Can you explain more?

Comment: @kjhughes I mean, if you use `xml_find_all(x, "link")`, as you said it only finds `<link>` tags direct children of the current node (which is the document), but the document has only one child and that's the `<items>` tag. How can `xml_find_all(x, "link")` find the `<link>' tags?

Comment: @kjhughes Oh I get it, `x` is not the document, @jakub read it as the document's children, which CAN be `<item>` tags. Idk if I'm right

Comment: I don't know the product in question, but 55ms for searching such a small document seems ridiculously slow, and I wonder whether there is something else going on. For example, is the cost actually going on parsing the XPath expression?